# Async lambda expression with await returns Task?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await

I have the following code:

```
            // Get all of the files from the local storage directory.
        var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

        // Map each file to a stream corresponding to that file.
        var streams = files.Select(async f => { return await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(); });
```

I would expect `streams` to be of type `IEnumerable<Stream>` but in fact it is of `IEnumberable<Task<Stream>>`, which is what I would've expected had I omitted the await keyword. The return type of `OpenStreamForWriteAsync` is `Task<Stream>` — surely awaiting it should produce a `Stream`?

So, why is the return await statement returning a Task?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: async methods always return `Task<T>` or `Task`. Select itself does not care about the return type. So it projects an enumerable Task because your select lambda is async. You could iterate over your collection and await the Stream.

Comment: Well, one can write an "async void" method, which is what I presumed was happening here.

How do I fix it?

Comment: @MatthewH If it was `void` the you'd have no idea when the async task finished and no way of getting any results (because there would be no results).  You really only want to have a `void` async method when it's an event handler, which this isn't.

Comment: If I write an async void method, it doesn't need to be awaited, whereas an async Task method does. So how can they be equivalent?

Comment: @MatthewH What vscjones probably meant is that anytime you have a non-`async` method that returns void and you turn it into an `async` method you should change it's return type from `void` to `Task`, because `Task` is a way for the caller to know when it finishes, but indicates it doesn't have a result.  Returning `void` just means the caller can't even know when it finishes.

Comment: `why is the return await statement returning a Task?` I +1'ed Servy's answer, but to put it simply: `await` unwraps a `Task<T>` to a `T`, and `async` wraps the `T` back into `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All `async` methods return either `void`, `Task`, or `Task<TResult>`.  The lambda is just an anonymous method, and thus that still applies.  It's essentially the same as this named method:

```
private static async Task<Stream> Foo(TypeGOesHere f )
{
    return await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(); 
}
```

In order to make it return a `Stream` it would need to be a blocking method, rather than an async method:

```
private static Stream Foo(TypeGOesHere f )
{
    return f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync().Result; 
}
```

You probably don't want that.

You can turn your `IEnumerable<Task<Stream>>` into a `Task<Stream[]>` by using `Task.WhenAll` if that helps you:

```
Task<Stream[]> resultTask = Task.WhenAll(streams);
```

Comment: Or, better, make the enclosing method async and use `var streams = files.Select(await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync());`.  It is not the lambda that needs to have the async modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldnt this be the best solution?

```
        // Get all of the files from the local storage directory.
    var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();

    // Map each file to a stream corresponding to that file and await the Task that waits for all tasks to complete? maybe thats whats being implied above...
    var streams = await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(async f => { return await f.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(); }));
```