# Using async to create an implicit task?

Tags: c#, async-await

In another answer roughly the following code was used:

```cs
c.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = async (context) => context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
```

The compiler warns on the arrow operator that the expression is not awaited in any form. Removing the `async` keyword confirms that `OnRedirectToAccessDenied` wants a function that returns a Task (`Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task>`) and the following can't build:

```cs
c.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (context) => context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
```

The `async` keyword is only used to convert the expression to a task, it seems. I haven't seen `async` used this way before.

The following code will not give any compiler warnings, but it doesn't look as elegant.

```cs
c.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (context) => Task.Run(
                                                    () => context.Response.StatusCode = 403
                                                 );
```

Is the compiler warning unwarranted, and is it a good idea to use `async` in this manner?

Comment: Have you tried returning Task.CompletedTask instead of marking it as async? Marking something as async does more than make it return a Task, it also sets up a state machine, which is unnecessary if you're not doing an asynchronous call.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @mason 's answer:

`c.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (ctx) => {ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403; return Task.CompletedTask; } `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If something needs a Task but you don't really have one, then you can return `Task.CompletedTask` to satisfy that requirement *and* to mark that handling is complete, while still keeping everything synchronous, and without the overhead of creating a state machine (which would be the result of using the `async` keyword):

```
c.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (context) =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree, but is the use of async in the example good or is it language abuse?

Comment: @CarlR I think the answer that Peter gave already explains why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @mason Reading your comment and Peters answer yes, but for another user just reading Peters answer it doesn't explain it completely. You know the Q n A style site this is. ;)

Comment: @CarlR No, it is not good use of `async`. `async` should be applied when you want to use `await` inside the routine. That is its only purpose, enabling the use of the keyword `await` inside. If you are using it for any other purpose, you are doing something wrong. Yes, [async lambdas will return a `Task`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13982263/11683), but non-async methods that return Tasks are just as awaitable as async methods that return Tasks. It's the task that is awaitable.

Comment: @GSerg I agree. Can we put it in Peter's answer so I can mark it as complete? :)

Comment: @CarlR It's already in Peter's answer, see the part about "without the overhead of creating a state machine".

Comment: @mason Your first comment was more complete. Sorry.

Comment: I added a note that relates the creation of the state machine to the async keyword.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted.

Comment: One important side note is that exception handling semantics are different without the `async`. So - while I agree that this is the correct solution *for this scenario* - this solution isn't broad enough to cover *every* "I need to return a `Task` but have nothing to `await`" problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also await something just to make the warning go away:

```
c.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = async (context) =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    await Task.CompletedTask; // Suppress the warning CS1998
};
```

The overhead of the state machine is negligible. So choose based on what you perceive as more natural and intuitive.

Comment: Without async await there is no warning. Peter's sample is complete.